# In c++, is it possible to specify part of the parameters for a template class

Tags: c++, templates

```
template<class A=int, class B=float, class C=double> class SomeClass;
```

Is it possible to specify only the last parameter with something like: `SomeClass<C=long long int>` ?

Comment: No, no named parameters so they have to be given in order.

Comment: you can apply similar tricks as with function parameters (eg write a `SomeClassWithCasFirstParam` wrapper that passes the desired defaults to the implementation)

Comment: Not out of the box, no. The Boost devs have a remarkable workaround to this in their Phoenix and Spirit libraries.

Comment: It is possible with a policy classes. But it requires some metaprogrammng.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In c++, is it possible to specify part of the parameters for a template class

Yes. If you don't specify all template parameters, then the unspecified ones will have the default (if a default has been specified).

> Is it possible to specify only the last parameter

Not as such. (Just like non-template parameters,) Template parameters are positional. It is not possible to specify parameters after unspecified parameters.

You can work around this using a template alias:

```
template<class C=double, class A=int, class B=float>
using PermutedSomeClass = SomeClass<A, B, C>;

PermutedSomeClass<long long> // same as SomeClass<int, float, long long>
```